# 3 Slashes appear after Apostrophe in custom fields after updating product-site

Tags: php, functions, custom-field

I am using custom fields to add some extras to the product pages. Therefore I hook into it via functions.php
But out of some reason in Wordpress-Backend when editing a product side, it adds 3 slashes before each apostrophe. Example: `src="..."` will result in `src=///"..///"`
[image]

each time I click save, its creating 3 new slashes. I tried stripslashes_deep() and stripslashes() but without success, like you see here:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'headline_placeholder');
function headline_placeholder () {
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, 'productheadline', true);
wp_reset_query();
}
```

Do you know what causes that problem?

**---- UPDATE ----**
I think I found a way, but its only reducing 2 backslashes, not all 3:

```
function removeslashes($string)
{
    $string=implode("",explode("\\",$string));
    return stripslashes(trim($string));
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'headline_placeholder');
function headline_placeholder () {
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
$meta = get_post_meta($postid, 'productheadline', true);
echo removeslashes($meta);
wp_reset_query();
}
```

Comment: I think that your use case doesn't justify the HTML in the custom field value; anyway, do you have anymore code involve in the process? I can not reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use more appropiate value in the custom field and **output it within HTML when needed**; for example the `productheadline` value could be only "Desktopia Pro", which is a more **real head line**, I can not imagine a headline value containing HTML markup, then you can output it within a HTML markup like this:

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <h1><?php echo get_post_meta( $postid, 'productheadline', true ); ?></h1>
</div>
```

I really think that this approach is much better and future proof. For example, using HTML markup in a custom field makes the custom field data unexportable and not reusable. For example, what happens if you need a different HTML markup in the future? You will have to edit every single custom field. Not very good. What if you need to access the product headline to be used elsewhere (feeds, REST API, etc)? You will get a HTML markup instead of the real headling; not very good.

Comment: thanks for your idea! Principle that would work, but for example the custom field "produkt-text" varies from product to product and it will always need different styling (and so the apostrophes). I am wondering, why this strange problem occurs.

Comment: The style needs does not conflict with my answer at all. Even more, the style needs can change in the future; with the suggested approach you will can update the output/CSS wihtout edit every custom field. Definetely, HTML and sytles in a custom field has no sense, at least for me and for this case.

Comment: I think I found a solution in here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta#Character_Escaping 

But I am a bit confused how to adjust my code, so its reducing 3 slashes?

`add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'headline_placeholder');
function headline_placeholder () {
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, 'productheadline', true);
wp_reset_query();
}`

Comment: I still think that in your case, HTML should be used on output only and not in the custom field value. Sorry but I really think you are taking a bad approach.